# How to deal with eslint complaints about used-vars for functions called from dom events

Tags: javascript, eslint

When the function is called from an event such as a mouse click on a button or link, eslint complains about `unused-vars` because the only reference is the attached event in the HTML page.

I like the `unused-vgars` warning otherwise.

My current approach is to disable the lines with the `eslint-disable` line comment, i.e.

```
const addStreetAddressLine = () => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

but now I am sprinkling that big comment throughout my code - 3 functions so far.

Is there another approach that is a bit cleaner?

Comment: Does the function get run from something like `<span onclick="addStreetAddressLine()">`?

Comment: yeah like from that

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to attach the listeners using Javascript. Inline handlers have [way too many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045): they have crazy scoping rules, require global pollution to work, and can require ugly escaping when the function needs to be called with a string argument.

Use `addEventListener` instead. Eg, change

```
<span onclick="addStreetAddressLine()">
```

to

```
<span class="someSpan">
```

```
document.querySelector('.someSpan').addEventListener('click', addStreetAddressLine);
```

That will get rid of the linter warning *and* make your code more maintainable.

The `someSpan` is just there to give you a way to select the element. You don't have to add a class, you just need *some* way to precisely select the element.

Comment: Personally, I don't like IDs since they [pollute the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) unnecessarily, which can result in bugs. I'd prefer to select it by using already-existing attributes of it or its ancestors. This is almost always possible. If not, you can add a class, like I did there. Or you can add an ID instead of a class, but a class may be a better choice.

Comment: Hmmm, excellent point.  How about a `data-` attribute.  Maybe like `data-address-form-addStreetAddressLine`